# rewritecond not working for existing files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with mod rewrite apache seems to ignore the rewrite cond.

The rewrite rule is working as all my pages are working but the problem is with resources like css, imgs and js. In my html I use `"href=assets/css/style.css"` which is an existing file but i i am redirected on my index.php...

Is there something i did wrong ?

here is my vhost config

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:*>
>     ServerAdmin me@local.loc
>     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/Covoiturage"
>     ServerName covoiturage.loc
>     ErrorLog "logs/covoiturage-error.log"
>     CustomLog "logs/covoiturage-access.log" combined
>     <directory c:/wamp/www/covoiturage/>
>         Allow from all
>         AllowOverride all
>     </directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

here is my htaccess :

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding `RewriteCond` to wrong `RewriteRule`. `RewriteCond` only in effect to very next `RewriteRule`. Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: can you explain why my solution was not correct please ?

Comment: Yes I wrote the reason above i.e. your last rule was without `RewriteCond` hence for css/js/images etc also `index.php` was being served.

Comment: ok so if i understand correctly, rewritecond are only for one rewriterule so in my case the last rule had no condition and was always executed ?